# materialized view over multiple databases

Tags: oracle, view, materialized-views

**Set-up :**
There is one TRANSPORT database and 4 PRODUNIT databases. All these 5 DBs are on different machines and are Oracle databases.

**Requirement :**

1. A 'UNIFIED view'  is required in the TRANSPORT db which will retrieve data from a **table that is present in all the 4 PRODUNIT databases**. So when there is a query on the TRANSPORT database(with where clause), the data may be present in any one of the 4 PRODUNIT databases
2. The query will be kind of 'real time' i.e it requires that as soon as the data is inserted/updated in the table of any of the 4 PRODUNIT databases, it is **IMMEDIATELY available in the TRANSPORT db**

I searched on the net and ended up with the [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm). I have the below concerns before I proceed :

1. Will the 'fast refresh on commit' ensure requirement 2 ?
2. The table in the individual PRODUNIT databases will experience frequent DML. I'm suspecting a performance impact on the TRANSPORT db - am I correct ? If yes, how shall I proceed ?

I'm rather wondering if there is an approach better than the materialized view !

Answer (score 1):

A materialized view that refreshes on commit cannot refer to a remote object so it doesn't do you a lot of good.  If you could do a refresh on commit, you could maintain the data in the transport database synchronously.  But you can't.

I would seriously question the wisdom of wanting to do synchronous replication in this case.  If you could, then the local databases would become unusable if the transport database was down or the network connection was unavailable.  You'd incur the cost of a two-phase commit on every transaction.  And it would be very easy for one of the `produnit` databases to block transactions happening on the other databases.

In virtually every instance I've ever come across, you'd be better served with asynchronous replication that keeps the `transport` database synchronized to within, say, a few seconds of the `produnit` database.  You probably want to look into GoldenGate or Streams for asynchronous replication with relatively short delays.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to 'asynchronous replication that keeps the transport database synchronized to within, say, a few seconds of the produnit database' ? Are you suggesting to use MV with some delay ?

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist - You could create materialized views that refresh every few minutes.  Like I said in my answer, though, you'd probably want to look into GoldenGate or Streams.  Those are technologies within the Oracle stack that are designed for asynchronously replicating data with less latency than materialized views.  Materialized views are easier to work with but they're not particularly efficient-- other technologies (Streams and GoldenGate) are more efficient architectures but they're generally more work to set up.

Answer (score 0):

whether or not you require a MV would depend on the performance between your DBs and the volume of data concerned.

I would start with a normal view, using DB links to select the data from the databases, but would need to test this to see that the performance is like.

Given requirement 2, a refresh on commit would probably be the best approach if performance on a normal view was poor.

Comment: Do you mean that a 'fast refresh on commit' MV is faster than a normal view ?

Comment: the query will probably be faster, but if the query from the normal view gives acceptable performance, then i wouldn't bother with the MV

Comment: You can't have a refresh on commit materialized view across a database link.